# How can I limit the amount for input? Powershell

Tags: powershell

How can I limit the amount for input?

```
$M = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your MM'  
$D = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input the DD'
$Y = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your YYYY'
```

I want to limit how many characters you can enter. To 2 or 4.
MM  only two characters.  Only numbers 
YYYY only four  characters.  Only numbers

Ex: when somebody enter more then 2 digits. It breaks 
 the rest of the commend. I just don’t know how to limit this in powershell.

Comment: Maybe a job for conditional IF logic for a starting point or ideas for others that have time and can help. This should be possible and seems pretty clear to me what you are asking. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_if?view=powershell-6

Comment: You should have edited your original question and then it would have been reopened. There was no need to create a new question. Questions are put on hold in order to be improved until they contain enough information to get good answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I limit input in Powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/1312381/how-do-i-limit-input-in-powershell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can validate the whole input in one step with the following script. I modified this from [a TechNet answer.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9933ba87-eb9c-4c16-9408-4cd5c2db0119/how-to-validate-the-date-and-time-format-entered-in-readhost?forum=winserverpowershell)

```
While(1){
    Try{
        $UserDate = [DateTime](Read-Host 'Enter date (MM/DD/YYYY)')
        Break
    }
    Catch{
        Write-Host 'Not a valid date. Enter MM/DD/YYYY' -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
$UserMonth = $UserDate.ToString('MM')
$UserDay = $UserDate.ToString('dd')
$UserYear = $UserDate.ToString('yyyy')
```

Comment: The good part of this script is that it can read any method of date input PowerShell supports for your location. So the user could input "April 10, 2018" and the script would still work. If "April 11" is entered, it will even fill in the current year.